# The relation between Hadamard products and Matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, hadamard-product

Is there any relation between the Hadarmad product and conventional matrix product? I'm trying to solve an optimization problem and I'm kind of stuck here. 
Let X, A, B, C are square matrices with same dimensions. A,B,C are known. How can I find X if :

$X\circ A + X.B = C$

I'm very appreciate for your help

Comment: In other words, $$X_{rc} A_{rc} + \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{ri} B_{ic} = C_{rc}$$or$$X_{rc} = \frac{ C_{rc} - \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{ri} B_{ic} }{ A_{rc} }$$i.e. each element of $X$ depends on that entire row of $X$. My Math-Fu fails me at this point (it was just here, but now gone!), but perhaps you could look into solving each row vector of $X$ at a time?

Comment: Thanks. I tried this way but the problem was still hard to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the SVD of the first coefficient matrix 
$$A = USV^T = \sum_k \sigma_ku_kv_k^T$$
where $(u_k, v_k)$ are the $k^{th}$ columns of $(U,V)$ respectively, and $\sigma_k$ is the $k^{th}$ element on the diagonal of $S$.

From this decomposition generate two sets of diagonal matrices
$$\eqalign{
 E_k &= {\rm Diag}(u_k) \cr
 F_k &= {\rm Diag}(v_k) \cr
}$$
The elementwise/Hadamard product can now be expressed as a sum
$$A\circ X = \sum_k \sigma_kE_kXF_k$$
We are now in a position to vectorize the original equation 
$$\eqalign{
 &IXB + \sum_k \sigma_kE_kXF_k = C \cr
 &\Big(B^T\otimes I + \sum_k \sigma_kF_k\otimes E_k\Big)\,{\rm vec}(X) = {\rm vec}(C) \cr
 &{\rm vec}(X) = \Big(B^T\otimes I + \sum_k \sigma_kF_k\otimes E_k\Big)^+\,{\rm vec}(C) \cr
}$$
where $M^+$ indicates the pseudoinverse of $M$.

De-vectorize this result, if you want a matrix solution.

**Update**

Some Julia code to test this solution method

```
m,n = 8,5;
A,C,B = randn(m,n), randn(m,n), randn(n,n);
U,S,V = svd(A); U *= diagm(S);
M = kron(V[:,1],U[:,1]); 

for k = 2:min(m,n)
  M += kron(V[:,k],U[:,k]); 
end

BM = kron(B',eye(m)) + diagm(M);
X = reshape(BM \ C[:], m, n);

vecnorm(X.*A + X*B - C)
9.188833363419665e-15
```

**Update 2**

By using sparse versions of the operators [notably speye() and spdiagm()] in the Kronecker step, Julia can solve moderately large systems with this method.

```
m,n = 100,100;
A,C,B = randn(m,n), randn(m,n), randn(n,n);
U,S,V = svd(A); U *= diagm(S);
M = kron(V[:,1],U[:,1]); 

for k = 2:size(V)[2]
  M += kron(V[:,k],U[:,k]); 
end

BM = kron(B', speye(m)) + spdiagm(M);
X = reshape(BM \ C[:], size(A));

vecnorm(X.*A + X*B - C)
4.2871786136044444e-11
```

**Update 3**

There is a way to solve the problem without calculating large Kronecker products.

If you multiply a Hadamard product (from the left or right) by a vector from the standard basis, it distributes over the terms in the product like so
$$\eqalign{
e_k^T(A\circ B) &= (e_k^TA)\circ(e_k^TB) \cr
(A\circ B)e_k &= (Ae_k)\circ(Be_k) \cr
}$$
We can use this to solve for the $X$ matrix, one row at a time
$$\eqalign{
e_k^T(X\circ A) + e_k^T(XB) &= e_k^TC \cr
(e_k^TX)\circ(e_k^TA) + (e_k^TX)B &= e_k^TC \cr
x_k^T\Big({\rm Diag}(a_k^T)+B\Big) &= c_k^T \cr
x_k^T &= c_k^T\Big({\rm Diag}(a_k^T)+B\Big)^+ \cr
}$$
The Julia code is simpler as well.

```
m,n = 100,100;
X,A,C,B = zeros(m,n), randn(m,n), randn(m,n), randn(n,n);

for k = 1:m
  X[k,:] = C[k,:]' / (diagm(A[k,:]) + B); 
end

vecnorm(X.*A + X*B - C)
1.2635927955948767e-11
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is a great solution to finding X. But I am wondering that is there any other solution that does not need to use Fronecker product? Because the Fronecker product creates matrices with large dimensions and may be not suitable to the computation.

Comment: @nam How big are your matrices?  Julia has some great sparse operators that allow me to use the above method on my laptop for matrices as large a $100\times 100$.  I've updated the answer with the sparse operators.

Comment: Yeah using sparse matrices is a great way to reduce the computation. But I'm working on huge matrices with 1000 X 1000 dimensions. Although the Fronecker product of matrix B' and eye(m) can be calculated, the inverse operator in the next line require a lot more memory. Do you know any way to handle it?

Comment: Spin up an AWS machine with **lots** of memory, install Julia, and give it a try.

Comment: I used sparse matrix techniques in Matlab and solved the problem. It takes about 1.6 seconds. Thanks for your help.